# why scala function parameters can't reassign to a new One?

Tags: scala

```
  class NodeL(a :Int){
    var value = a
  }

  def change(x :NodeL) = {
    if(x == null) x = new Node
  }
```

when I use code above ,compiler give me an error "reassignment to val" in the statement "if(x == null) x = new Node" why?

Comment: By default, method parameters are `val` in Scala.

Comment: @SudhirSingh Not "by default", they can't be `var` at all.

Answer (score 5):

You can't, method parameters are immutable in scala (i.e., they are `vals`)